# bash script - fetch only unique domains from email list to variable

Tags: regex, bash

I am new to bash and having problem understanding how to get this done.

Check all "To:" field email address domains and list all unique domains to a variable to compare it to from domain.

I get the "from address" domain by using

```
grep -m 1 "From: " filename | cut -f 2 -d '@' | cut -d ">" -f 1
```

when reading a mail stored in file filename.

For "to address" domain there can be multiple To: addresses and having multiple domains. I am not sure how to get unique domains from "to address field".

Example to address line will be like this:

```
To: user@domain.com, user2@domain.com, 
    User Name <sample@domaintest.com>, test@domainname.com
```

```
grep -m 1 "^To: " filename | cut -f 2 -d '@' | cut -d ">" -f 1
```

but there are different format of email. So I am not sure if `grep` is right or if I should search for awk or something.

I need to get the unique domain list from the "To:" field email address/addresses to a variable in bash script.

Desired output for above example:

```
domain.com,domaintest.com,domainname.com
```

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -m 1 "^To: " filename | grep -Po '@\K[^, >]+'`?

Comment: @Cyrus that worked but apparently "To:" field is in two lines. The "User Name" part in example has gone to next line in actual email file and grep only checks one line i think? so it only got 2 domain of first 2 email ids.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I have added an output request, thanks for help @Cyrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hellbent on doing this with line-oriented utilities, there is a utility `formail` in the Procmail distribution which can normalize things for you somewhat.

```
bash$ formail -czxTo: <<\==test==
> From: me <sender@example.com>
> To: you <first@example.org>,
>    them <other@example.net>
> Subject: quick demo
>
> Very quick, innit.
> ==test==
first@example.org,    other@example.net
```

So with that you have input which you can actually pass to `grep` or Awk ... or `sed`.

```
fromdom=$(formail -czxTo: <message | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/.*@//')
```

The `From:` address will not be normalized by `formail -czxFrom:` but you can use a neat trick: make `formail` generate a reply back to the `From:` address, and then extract the `To:` header from that.

```
todoms=$(formail -rtzcxTo: <message | sed 's/.*@//')
```

In some more detail, `-r` says to create a new reply to whoever sent you `message`, and then we do `-zcxTo:` on *that.*

(The `-t` option may or may not do what you want. In this case, I would perhaps omit it. http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/formail.html has (vague) documentation for what it does; see also the section just before http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#group-writable and sorry for the clumsy link -- there doesn't seem to be a good page-internal anchor to link to.)

Comment: I will accept this as answer since it does what i asked, but reading your idea. we decided on doing all the bash script part on php instead. so i will have to write everything differently now. thanks for help.

Comment: PHP would not exactly be my first choice for this, but good luck! (-:

Answer (score 0):

Email address normalization is tricky because there are so many variants to choose from.

```
From: Elvis Parsley <king@graceland.example.com>
From: king@graceland.example.com
From: "Parsley, Elvis" <king@graceland.example.com> (kill me, I have to use Outlook)
From: "quoted@string" <king@graceland.example.com> (wait, he is already dead)
To: This could fold <recipient@example.net>,
   over multiple lines <another@example.org>
```

I would turn to a more capable language with proper support for parsing all of these formats. My choice would be Python, though you could probably also pull this off in a few lines of Ruby or Perl.

The `email` library was revamped in Python 3.6 so this assumes you have at least that version.  The [`email.Headerregistry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.headerregistry.html) class which is new in 3.6 is particularly convenient here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from email.policy import default
from email import message_from_binary_file
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append('-')

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg == '-':
        handle = sys.stdin
    else:
        handle = open(arg, 'rb')

    message = message_from_binary_file(handle, policy=default)
    from_dom = message.get('From').address.domain
    to_doms = set()
    for addr in message.get('To').addresses:
        dom = addr.domain
        if dom == from_dom:
            continue
        to_doms.add(dom)
    print(','.join([from_dom] + list(to_doms)))

    if arg != '-':
        handle.close()
```

This simply produces a comma-separated list of domain names; you might want to do the rest of the processing in Python too instead, or change this so that it prints something in a slightly different format.

You'd save this in a convenient place (say, `/usr/local/bin/fromto`) and mark it as executable (`chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/fromto`).  Now you can call this from the shell like any other utility like `grep`.

Comment: i dont think i can use python as this is actually done with postfix content filter for altermime.

Comment: If you can use shell script, you can call Python from that shell script. See updated last paragraph.

Comment: is it not possible to do from awk or some other native commands? because calling a python script and returning values back to shell script would cause lot more time delay i feel. i have to process the incoming mail and make changes according to mail and send a mail. so time becomes a factor. its not possible in bash commands only?

Comment: Nothing is impossible but I would hate to have to reimplement all that nice Python library code in Awk (and I have done something like that more than once, and always regretted it). I would not be surprised if Python turned out to be as fast as Awk in the end anyway.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve in terms of Postfix integration?

Comment: just to consider what is going on in python script. binary file input is mail file right? and its printing from and to domain fields to stdout? i will have to return values to bash script instead since i need those fields to compare with existing bash variables in script.

Comment: well i process a mail file and i need to figure out whether the mail is internal mail or external mail which decides my next sequence of code execution.

Comment: Yeah, it reads the file as binary because you can't trust it to be in UTF-8 (email still typically isn't) and parses out those two fields. The print formatting could be changed to have e.g. the From: domain in the first column and the To: domain(s) in subsequent fields, comma separated, for example.

Comment: I updated the code to produce this and fixed a silly bug in the process.